# remove table tr that have specific content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form inside SharePoint 2013 web application :-

[image]

I need to remove all the Table `<tr>` except the ones that start with `"name" & "title"`. so can anyone adivce how i can achieve this ? . here is part of the markup for the above image (it show two Tr on that have Content Type (should be removed), while the other contain Name ):-

```
<table id="formTbl" class="ms-formtable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 8px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" valign="top" nowrap="true">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">Content Type</h3>
</td>
<td class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" width="113px" valign="top" nowrap="true">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>
Name
<span class="ms-accentText" title="This is a required field."> *</span>
</nobr>
</h3>
</td>
<td class="ms-formbody" width="350px" valign="top">
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" width="113px" valign="top" nowrap="true">
<td class="ms-formbody" width="350px" valign="top">
</tr>
```

Now i have jquery version 1.7 loaded inside the web application, but i prefer to achieved using pure javaScript.

Thanks

**EDIT** here is a more detailed markup  :-

```
<div id="contentRow">
<div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
<div id="contentBox" aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite">
<div id="notificationArea" class="ms-notif-box"></div>
<div id="DeltaPageStatusBar">
<div id="customcalender"></div>
<div id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain">
<a id="mainContent" tabindex="-1" name="mainContent"></a>
<div style="padding-left:5px">
<table id="onetIDListForm" class="ms-core-tableNoSpace">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="ms-webpart-zone ms-fullWidth">
<div id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" class="s4-wpcell-plain ms-webpartzone-cell ms-webpart-cell-vertical ms-fullWidth ">
<div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-vertical ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth ">
<div id="WebPartWPQ2" class="noindex " style="" allowdelete="false" width="100%" haspers="false" webpartid="6c7d849e-da6b-4138-be9f-b99bde542065">
<table class="ms-informationbar" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
<div id="listFormToolBarTop" style="display: none;">
<span style="display:none">
<span></span>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%" valign="top">
<table id="formTbl" class="ms-formtable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 8px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" valign="top" nowrap="true">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">Content Type</h3>
</td>
<td class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" width="113px" valign="top" nowrap="true">
<h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>
Name
<span class="ms-accentText" title="This is a required field."> *</span>
</nobr>
</h3>
</td>
<td class="ms-formbody" width="350px" valign="top">
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" width="113px" valign="top" nowrap="true">
<td class="ms-formbody" width="350px" valign="top">
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: First, your pictures are incredibly hard to see. Expect down votes. Second, what have you tried? I don't see any attempts at anything in JavaScript. What have you tried so far so that we can improve on it?

Comment: @dman2306 most all pictures on SO are small like this, right click the image then select "open image in new tab" to see them full size ; )

Comment: So loop through the rows and look at the text in the first cell.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, call me crazy, but I figure as the guy providing help, I shouldn't have to work for it, that the poster should. Meaning, upload it to imgur or something so it makes it easier on the people donating their time to help ;)

Comment: @john G:please note (from comments), that any jQuery solution should either be placed after the elements it references (e.g. end of `body`), or inside a DOM ready handler.

Comment: It may be safer to filter on the form field ID than the label text. Those aren't subject to padding and administrator changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is your friend:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/jjzx6mge/4/

```
$('#formTbl tr').filter(function () {
    return !$(".ms-standardheader", this).text().match(/Name|Title/i);
}).remove();
```

The result returned of a function passed to filter is a boolean value telling which items to retain (truthy), or which to exclude (falsey).

This one targets only rows that have the requested text in the `ms-standardheader` classed element.

It also only targets a specific inner table to avoid the case of deep searching from the top level table and wiping out entire tables within it.

While you can do this with plain old JS, significantly more code is required.As you already have a version of jQuery installed, it makes sense to use it.

Comment: I think you misread the question. «I need to remove all the Table <tr> except the ones that start with "name" & "title". »

Comment: That's better :) @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie but this have removed the whole table and all its Tr can u adivce ? i think this is because the current table i within another table

Comment: @john G: Would need to see a complete example of your implementation. As you can see my JSFiddle works, in isolation, so the theory is sound :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes it is my fault , i edit my original question with a more details markup .. can you advice.. i think the current table is defined as a Tr for antoher table ... that why ur code removed the whole table..

Comment: @john G: The HTML you just posted is invalid. You have stacks of TRs nested which cannot be correct. Basically nested tables need a bit more work. If you can clean up the HTML, I will add some changes :)

Comment: @john G: If you add a specific table selector (answer updated) it will only target the inner table. The problem was that the `tr` alone would match the parent table first and wipe out everything based on the first ms-standardheader!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie your script worked well on our test server , but when i wrote the script on our live server the script raised the folloiwing error "SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'ListId' of undefined or null reference "

Comment: You would need to show the relevant code. It may be you are ripping out rows that are referenced? Test by changing the `remove()` to `hide()`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie so what are the differences between .remove & .hide in this case ?

Comment: Hide will leave the DOM elements in place, just sets `style="display: none"`, so that any code referencing them will continue to work. Just try it and see if that error still occurs. If it does, you may need to `hide` instead of `remove` to ensure the rest of the page keeps working.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#formTbl tr').each(function() {
    var frstVal = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
    if (!frstVal.match(/name|title/i)) {
      $(this).remove()
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="formTbl" class="ms-formtable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin-top: 8px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-formlabel" valign="top" nowrap="true">
                <h3 class="ms-standardheader">Content Type</h3>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-formlabel" width="113px" valign="top" nowrap="true">

                <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>
Title
<span class="ms-accentText" title="This is a required field."> *</span>
</nobr>
</h3>

            </td>
            <td class="ms-formbody" width="350px" valign="top">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-formlabel" width="113px" valign="top" nowrap="true">
                <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
<nobr>
Name
<span class="ms-accentText" title="This is a required field."> *</span>
</nobr>
</h3>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-formbody" width="350px" valign="top">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ms-formlabel" width="113px" valign="top" nowrap="true">
                    <td class="ms-formbody" width="350px" valign="top">
            </tr>
```

Comment: i wrote the following at the end of my web page :- <script>
$('#formTbl tr').map(function(){
  var frstVal = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
  if( !frstVal.match(/name|title/i)){
    return $(this).remove()
  }
   return $(this);
 });
</script> but did not have any effect..

Comment: @johnG You might want to try my plain JS (without jQuery) soloution

Comment: @StefanWittwer why is that?

Comment: @DelightedD0D He said in the question he would prefer it achieved using plain JS

Comment: @johnG see my update above, slight change but your issue is probably that you need to add the code inside a "dom ready" function so it is not run until after the page loads

Comment: @StefanWittwer yeah I know but OP also seemed open to a jQuery solution which reads a lot easier than pure js does, anyway, im sure the OP will find your answer without the need of a road map ; )

Comment: Your answer also does what was expected, so +1 to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove every `tr` that has a `.ms-standardheader` element that contains the text `Name` or `Title`

```
$('#formTbl tr').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   var label = that.find('.ms-standardheader').text();       
   if (label.indexOf('Name') != -1 || label.indexOf('Title') != -1) {
      that.remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Just providing the main idea. He can check against any text

Comment: it should be || not &&

Comment: @kapantzak since there are around 14 rows and i only need to show two fields one named "Name" while the other named "Title",, so how i can say to keep the rows that start with either Name or Title, i want to specify Start with and not equal, since i might chnage the Name to be "Name (this will be shown on the page title)"..

Comment: label.indexOf('Name') will return zero or anything greater that zero if the string 'Name' is inside the label. So this will return true even if the label do not start with 'Name'

Answer (score 0):

And here I am, doing this the good ol' plain JS way, since you've asked for it :)
http://jsfiddle.net/m53esfpo/3/

**Edit:** Updated code and fiddle (thanks @TrueBlueAussie)

Removes every tr except the ones that start with name or title.

```
var t = document.getElementById('formTbl');

for (var i = 0; i < t.getElementsByTagName("tr").length; i++) {
    var s = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].getElementsByClassName('ms-formlabel');
    if (s.length > 0) {
        if (s[0].innerText.indexOf('Name') < 0 && s[0].innerText.indexOf('Title') < 0) {
            t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i].parentNode.removeChild(t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code will match the text anywhere, in any element, in the row. You need to target a bit more aggressively.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yeah, but that's why I use .indexOf instead of ==

Comment: Sorry, your indexOf will match that text anywhere in any element in the row

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie That's maybe because there is only a Name and a Content Type element? ;) The js code matches, I copy-pasted it. For the content I just used the html provided in the question, which does only include a name and a content type tr

Comment: `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V` on a row perhaps? (or just copy from mine. I don't mind) :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with this:

```
 $("#formTbl tr td h3").not("h3:contains('Name'):contains('Title')").closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Well you can add as many `:contain()` selectors you want. Updated the answer for title as well.

Comment: Sorry that does an *and*... He needs an OR condition. As I was saying, this particular technique can *only* work for one string.